# Meteor Accounts Routing

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes, meteor-accounts

I use Meteor Accounts package but not the accounts-ui.
If I send a verify email when user is created the following link is provided in the email: `http://localhost:3000/#/verify-email/06apVGBQypZAzpXZp4bPOYzn0-jCS9rR7ENkr8jkQRr`
If I open this link this route is redirected to `http://localhost:3000/#` and the template I defined for `/` is rendered. I can then access the `Accounts._verifyEmailToken` thats not a problem. But I dont want this route `/#` to be taken.

How can I say the Accounts package that I want to be redirected to my the route I want (in my case `/app`)?

My attempts so far:

1. Redirect `/#` with iron router to `/app` ==> not working
2. Having a look in the source code of accounts package. There are URLS provided with `Meteor.absoluteUrl`. But I don't want to change the source code of the package.

What ideas do you have to let the package route to `/app` afterwards and still have the token accessable in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the url of the different mails in the Account package, like this

```
 Accounts.urls.verifyEmail= function(token){
    return Meteor.absoluteUrl("/app/"+token+"/");
 };
```

Just overwrite the method on the server side.